# How to get form value and implement to Database Mysql using SQL Adapter IBM Worklight?

Tags: android, mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I Want to create a simple login apps in IBM Worklight , the value of username and password get from HTML form. What the Adapter query and how get the value of username and password in SQL Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with IBM Worklight by reading and learning from the [Getting 
Started material](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).

The first part of your question is covered in the [form-based authentication training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/08_02_Form_based_authentication.pdf) ([sample application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/FormBasedAuthentication.zip)), where you have a simple login form on application launch.

I don't understand the SQL part of the question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: Yes i have read the Getting Started material, well i will explain more ..i have table data in mysql for example (username and password). and i want to access the data as login authentication in HTML form. i don't know how create a query in -impl.js using SQL Adapter.

Comment: This scenario is a bit strange... you have an application with a login form, and you want to access a database to get the username and password, but if you have authentication and you want to use an adapter, you first have to be logged in, so you can't use the adapter in this manner - to fetch the username and password to use in the login form. I think you need to edit your question and explain - in detail - what your real scenario is. Sounds like you may want to look at LDAP...